# finger for Windows

Tags: windows, active-directory, unix

Ok probably a bit of an odd question, but is there a way to enable "finger" like functionality on a Windows network?

we'd basically like the ability to find out where a user is logged in on a network and possibly which users are logged onto a workstation if possible.

We're currently on AD2003 functional level, with the intent of going to AD2008 very soon, so compatibility in that arena is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those tasks are available via Mark Russinovich’s [PsLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx) tool.

To find out who is logged on to a computer:

```
psloggedon \\computername
```

To find out where a user is logged on in a domain:

```
psloggedon username
```

Comment: pslogged on only works in certain circumstances the details are mentioned on the download page

Comment: Jim, what situations have you seen it not show a user being logged on? psloggedon has worked well enough when I’ve needed to find people.

Answer (score 1):

in Powershell you would do:

```
gwmi win32_computersystem -computer $computers | select name , username
```

Where $computers is a list of the computers you want to check.  You cna get that via file:

```
$computers = get-content c:\server.txt
```

or via AD see [How Can I Use Windows PowerShell to Get a List of All My Computers?](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/11/09/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-get-a-list-of-all-my-computers.aspx)

and if you want turn the wmi call into a function and alias it to finger

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but you can get the information you are looking for with some scripting.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\COMPUTERNAME\root\cimv2") 
Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each objComputer in colComputer
    Wscript.Echo objComputer.UserName
Next
```

You could get a list of your workstations, either via text file or AD query and run that for each workstation. I'm sure there is a way to do something similar with PowerShell too.

Answer (score 0):

nbtscan.exe is useful tool.

http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html

It not only scan's shares it also indicates who signed on.